# Помогите доделать врага на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

Сделал врагу код:

```cs
GameObject player;
const float speedMove = 3.5f;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}

void Update()
{
    float direction = player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
    if (Mathf.Abs(direction) < 10)
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += Mathf.Sign(direction) * speedMove * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Но мне хочется сделать еще так, чтобы он ходил туда-сюда или хотя бы возвращался на то место, где и стоял.
А как это сделать я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Заставляешь его идти в одну строну, при остережении определенной точки заставляешь идти в другую и все в цикл

Comment: Да, я так и делал, но при достижении другой точки он просто шел до бесконечности в право. С чем это связанно я знаю, но как исправить не понимаю.

Comment: А вы сделали, что бы при достижении другой точки он поворачивался и опать шел к первой точке

Comment: Да теперь исправил и все сделал, но опять же появился вопрос я написал такой код

`void Run() {
Vector3 direction = transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(start.position, end.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time/arriveTime, 1f));
sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0f;}`
но не знаю как поместить его в Update